# Linear Algebra library for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra

I don't need anything fancy; basically, if it will let me do some basic Matrix*Matrix stuff I'll be happy.

Comment: is this: http://paczynski.net/testarea/matrix.html ? the web is full of them

Comment: https://github.com/cgrabowski/xform-js/

Answer (score 29):

You could use [numericjs.com](http://www.numericjs.com/). It's a javascript numerical analysis library that I'm working on that has several standard matrix algorithms for arbitrary sized dense matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Numericjs.com is good for front end. It is not a great module for nodejs backend.
In my project, I use this module: [node-sylvester](https://github.com/NaturalNode/node-sylvester).
It also has a nice explanation page: [The Sylvester Matrix Library Comes to Node.js](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/sylvester_node_js_matrix_vector_math)
I like this module a lot after some digging including read this page.

Comment: [Here is my fork](https://github.com/KOLANICH/sylvester/), I've added some features needed in gamedev. The official repo is seemed to be dead.