# Javascript equivalent functions to Matlab Functions: Polyfit/Polyval?

Tags: javascript, math, matlab, linear-algebra

Desperately need a Javascript equivalent to polyval and polyfit functions that exist in Matlab.  Essentially those functions in matlab do a curve fit based on two equally sized arrays depending on a specified polynomial.  I need to do some calculations that involve curve fitting in javascript and can't for the life of me find an equivalent function.

This is MatLab's explanation of the function polyfit

> "P = POLYFIT(X,Y,N) finds the coefficients of a polynomial P(X) of
>       degree N that fits the data Y best in a least-squares sense. P is
>   a
>       row vector of length N+1 containing the polynomial coefficients in
>       descending powers, P(1)*X^N + P(2)*X^(N-1) +...+ P(N)*X + P(N+1)."

This is MatLab's explanation of polyval.

> "POLYVAL Evaluate polynomial.
>       Y = POLYVAL(P,X) returns the value of a polynomial P evaluated at
>   X. P
>       is a vector of length N+1 whose elements are the coefficients of
>   the
>       polynomial in descending powers.
>
> ```
>     Y = P(1)*X^N + P(2)*X^(N-1) + ... + P(N)*X + P(N+1)"
> ```

Any help would be super.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POLYFIT` performs a [least-square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html) [polynomial fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates) which comes down to solving a [system of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations). I did a quick search, but I couldn't find a basic [linear algebra Javascript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286837/linear-algebra-library-for-javascript) that solves such systems... The easiest method would be to implement the [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) algorithm yourself.

`POLYVAL` is simply evaluating the polynomial at the points X by substituting the coefficients in the equation.

Comment: Ya I was thinking of rewriting Polyfit on my own, but was hoping there was a library or something in Javascript.

Comment: It comes down to solving a system of linear equations, but if you have many points, you're much better off using a Singular Value Decomposition. There is some code there: view-source:http://users.telenet.be/paul.larmuseau/SVD.htm

Comment: I wrote something for this, since it didn't exist!  https://github.com/prismofeverything/cyclops .  It will also generate a function for you from the resulting coefficients that calculates the polynomial for a given index value.

Comment: @prismoeverything: +1 thank you for sharing your code (you should post an answer preferably with some explanation). I see you are using the excellent numeric.js library to compute the SVD (by now it is THE best javascript library for any numerical computation)

Answer (score 3):

[numericjs](http://www.numericjs.com/) may help you get started.

Comment: The numeric.js site is down but you can still get the code on GitHub: https://github.com/sloisel/numeric/blob/master/src/numeric.js

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this code might help someone

```
function _prepare(_mat) {
_mat=[[]].concat(_mat)
for(i=0;i<_mat.length;++i)
    _mat[i]=[0].concat(_mat[i])
return _mat
}

function linear(_mat){
_mat=_prepare(_mat)
return _solve(_mat)
}


function _solve(_mat){
var c=new Array(),d=new Array()
var n=_mat.length-1

for(i=0;i<=n+1;i++) {
    d[i]=new Array();
    c[i]=0
    for(j=0;j<=n+1;++j)
        d[i][j]=0
}

// mission impossible
// calculate all the determinants of the system
for(m=2; m<=n ; ++m) {
    for(i=m;i<=n;++i)
        for(j = m-1;j<=n+1;++j)
            d[i][j] = [_mat[i][j] * _mat[m-1][m-1] , _mat[i][m-1]]
        for(i=m;i<=n;++i)
            for(j=m-1;j<=n+1;++j) {
                _mat[i][j] = d[i][j][0]-d[i][j][1]*_mat[m-1][j] 
                if(Math.abs(_mat[i][j])<1e-25) _mat[i][j]=0  // i have to add this line
            }
}
// now the coefficients of equation (not exactly)

for(i=n;i>=1;--i) {
    c[i-1] = _mat[i][n+1]
    if (i!=n)
    for(j=n; j>=i+1;--j)
        c[i-1] = c[i-1] -_mat[i][j] * c[j-1]
    if(_mat[i][i]!=0)
        c[i-1]=c[i-1] / _mat[i][i]
    else
        c[i-1]=0
    if(Math.abs(c[i-1])<1e-25)
        c[i-1]=0
}
c.length=n
return c
}

function fitpoly(e,b){
var a=new Array()
var n = 1+b,e=[[0,0]].concat(e),ns=e.length-1
for(i=0;i<=n+1;i++) {
    a[i]=new Array();
    for(j=0;j<=n+1;++j)
        a[i][j]=0
}
for(m=1;m <= n;m++)
    for(i=1;i<= m;i++) {
        j = m - i + 1; 
        for(ii=1;ii <= ns;ii++)
            a[i][j] = a[i][j] + Math.pow(e[ii][0], m-1)
    }  
for(i=1;i<= n;++i)
    for(ii=1;ii<=ns;++ii)
        a[i][n+1] = a[i][n+1] +e[ii][1]*Math.pow(e[ii][0],i-1) 
for(m = n+2 ; m <= 2*n ; ++m)
    for(i = m-n; i<= n;++i) {
        j= m -i 
        for(ii=1; ii<=ns;++ii)
            a[i][j] = a[i][j] + Math.pow(e[ii][0],m-2) // coefficients of system
    }
a.length=a.length-1  
return _solve(a)
}


//and then
poly_degree = 6
points= [[2,2],[2,4],[4,6],[6,4],[8,2]]
// coefficients of polynome 
console.log(fitpoly(points, poly_degree))

// or solve a linear system. Here with six variables
solution = linear([[1,2,3,-2,-3,-26,52],[3,2,5,-2,4,30,-60],[6,1,-4,-1,5,94,-188],[-1,2,4,3,4,30,-60],[-1,4,2,-1,2,26,-52],[3,-3,11,-7,-2,-1,-95]])
console.log(solution)
```

Comment: THanks dude but I'm already done with the development of this and haven't touched it in ages.  

I ended up employing Sylvesters Library for matrix computation/manipulation and then hand rolled my own solution.  I could post it here if anyone is interested.

Comment: @Spets - thanks!, I'm interested (if this is not too much trouble from your end..)

Answer (score 0):

Give [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jgphilpott/d38279e8fac9af31054e10b7363bf17e) a try, it uses [numeric.js](https://github.com/sloisel/numeric/blob/master/src/numeric.js):

```
function polyfit(xArray, yArray, order) {

  if (xArray.length <= order) console.warn("Warning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned.")

  let xMatrix = []
  let yMatrix = numeric.transpose([yArray])

  for (let i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {

    let temp = []

    for (let j = 0; j <= order; j++) {

      temp.push(Math.pow(xArray[i], j))

    }

    xMatrix.push(temp)

  }

  let xMatrixT = numeric.transpose(xMatrix)

  let dot1 = numeric.dot(xMatrixT, xMatrix)
  let dot2 = numeric.dot(xMatrixT, yMatrix)

  let dotInv = numeric.inv(dot1)

  let coefficients = numeric.dot(dotInv, dot2)

  return coefficients

}
```

Comment: Also see this post for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28301054/1544937