# Solve set of linear equations with javascript

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra

What is the best way to solve sets of linear equations using JavaScript?

I would like to find a solution for vector r

```
M*r = b
```

where M is a Matrix and b is a vector.

I understand that JavaScript isn't the best computational language, i'm simply hoping to implement my algorithm in JS for rapid prototyping.

Any references to other questions or help would be awesome! thanks in advance.

Comment: See here for some available tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753489/javascript-computer-algebra-system

Comment: Also here for linear algebra libraries in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286837/linear-algebra-library-for-javascript

Comment: "I'm pretty amazed this didn't come up in my pre-ask search" that's because it's not an appropriate question for [SO], and [your question should be closed as off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/153542).

Comment: @zzBov I think I understand the issue.  I rephrased the question... is this better? thanks

Comment: For future googlers: Using [algebra.js](http://algebra.js.org/) and combining `Equation.solveFor()` and `Equation.eval()`, you can solve a system of equations with the substitution method. An example with two equations: https://jsfiddle.net/38wpbteu/